# JavaScript date compare fails but prints same value

Tags: javascript

The following code does not compare two date.

```
var dateTextB=columns[0];
        var dateB = new Date(dateTextB);

        alert(dateA+' '+dateB);

        if (dateA==dateB)
        {
        // code
        }

        dateA= new Date(dateTextB);
```

That prints

Mon Aug 18 2014 23:30:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)----------Mon Aug 18 2014 23:30:00 GMT+0600 (Central Asia Standard Time)

But Does not fulfill if condition. But prints same values sometimes.

I  have tried  `if (dateA==dateB.getTime())` also.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: to be safe in javascript you should always use `===` as comparison operator ([see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons))

Comment: I have tried also. It did not work.

Comment: I didn't say it was the solution. That's why I didn't post an answer. I just wanted to point out that this is the better operator for comparison with equal signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried

```
if (dateA.getTime()==dateB.getTime())
{
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried but does not work either.

Comment: @tanvir please share a fiddle in that case

Comment: @ gurvinder: here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/tanvirbd/e42ack2L/1/

Comment: @tanvir updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/e42ack2L/2/ you still need to check for getTime()

Comment: Thank you so much. Now found I what was the problem. Initial value of dateA was null. That's way `if (dateA.getTime()==dateB.getTime())` was showing error

Comment: @tanvir if it has helped you, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer